# Seemingly defined javascript variable throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined

Given the following code, I'm not sure why I can retrieve longAndObscureVariableName but not anotherLongObscureVariableName. Can you explain, and show how I could make anotherLongObscureVariableName accessible from jsFileNumberTwo.js?

Head of HTML document originally contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="my_globals">
var longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFileNumberOne.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFileNumberTwo.js" /></script>
```

Javascript file jsFileNumberOne.js contains this code, which adds another global variable into the #my_globals element:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Store the initial variables, to which we will add more
    var initialVars = jQuery('#my_globals').html();
    // Define content for script tag:
    var scriptContent = initialVars;
    // Add to the script content
    scriptContent += 'var anotherLongObscureVariableName = "bar";\n';

    function insertNewInfo() {
        jQuery('#my_globals').html(scriptContent);
    };

    insertNewInfo();
});
```

When jsNumberOne.js executes, #my_globals changes to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="my_globals">
var longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";
var anotherLongAndObscureVariableName = "bar";
</script>
```

Javascript file jsFileNumberTwo.js contains this code, trying to find out the value of anotherLongAndObscureVariableName:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('longAndObscureVariableName'); // log displays "foo"
    console.log('anotherLongAndObscureVariableName'); // log displays "Uncaught ReferenceError: anotherLongAndObscureVariableName is not defined"
    console.log('window.anotherLongAndObscureVariableName'); // log displays "undefined"
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(window.anotherLongAndObscureVariableName);
    },2000); // log still displays "undefined"
});
```

I can't retrieve anotherLongAndObscureVariableName from within jsFileNumberTwo.js, even though I thought I was adding it to the global scope by putting it into the head of the HTML document.

Is this a scope issue? Is this a timing/sequencing issue? I think that jsFileNumberTwo.js may be accessing the head content before jsFileNumberOne.js executes, but even with the setTimeout function added I still get "undefined".

What is going on? How can I make this work?

Comment: Haven't you heard? "seemingly defined" is a new variable type in ECMAScript 7! Jokes aside, modifying the html of a script tag doesn't make the javascript interpreter execute the script again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts are running from top to bottom. So the second script modifies the first, which has already run and will not run again, so effectively has no effect.

Additionally, you should put things on the window to make globals.

So replace

```
scriptContent += 'var anotherLongObscureVariableName = "bar";\n';

function insertNewInfo() {
    jQuery('#my_globals').html(scriptContent);
};

insertNewInfo();
```

with

```
window.anotherLongAndObscureVariableName = "bar";
```

,

```
var longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";
```

with

```
window.longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";
```

Comment: I see! Would this be better:

`
<script type="text/javascript" id="my_globals">
window.longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";
</script>
`
or even:

`
window.longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";
window.anotherLongAndObscureVariableName = '';
`

The 2nd way would let people know that the anotherLongAndObscureVariableName variable exists & can be modified (my intention). Then it could have its value changed from jsFileNumberTwo.js as you suggest.

What's the difference between `longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";` and `window.longAndObscureVariableName = "foo";` ?

Comment: window.too makes it clear you're deliberately making it global. But ask another question...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to an existing script element in `jsfileNumberOne.js`, it would be better to just include the global variable in that file. In your `jsfileNumberOne.js`, just include the global variable like this:

```
window.anotherLongObscureVariableName = "bar";
```